# Возможно ли в таблице писать текст по разным сторонам ячейки?

Tags: html, css

Возможно ли сделать по бокам ячейки таблицы какой то текст и как возможно это сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Для начала начните с простого нарисовать таблицу данные которые есть только по углам и убрать ненужные границы. Потом по той же схеме усложнить ее.

Comment: Можно позиционировать элементы относительно ячейки

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Два разных текста на одной строке</title>
  <style>
  .leftstr, .rightstr {
   float: left; /* Обтекание справа */ 
   width: 50%; /* Ширина текстового блока */ 
  }
  .rightstr {
   text-align: right; /* Выравнивание по правому краю */ 
  }
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <p class="leftstr">Строка один</p>
 <p class="rightstr">Строка два</p>
 <div style="clear: left"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```